# When a button is clicked I want ajax to redirect towards a url but it is not working

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to create a SPA, using django and javascript, I have a home page with two buttons on it (Sign up and sign in), I want that when signup button is clicked, ajax redirects towards signup url
Here is my code

js

```
$('#id_register').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'register',
        method:"GET",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
})
```

Here is my html

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="content">
        <h3 id="home">Feeling Hungry?</h3>
        <h4 id="home_para">Order right now!</h4>
        <div>
            <button id="id_sign" type="button">Sign In</button>
            <button id="id_register" type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

It is successfully returning me the data but not redirecting towards the required url.

here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('register', RegisterView.as_view()),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="home")
]
```

I will be very thankful for the help

Comment: If you want to load new page, use `<a href="">` instead of a button.

Comment: you either can acheive this with the front end window.location.href = '/path'; or through backend but I don thave your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this

```
$('#id_register').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/register/',
        method:"GET",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
})
```

then the  urls.py

```
path('register/', RegisterView.as_view()),
```

Comment: Now I am unable to get any data as I apply post method right after that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AJAX for this. If you want to redirect the user to another page, don't use a button with AJAX attached to it, use an  tag instead.